# add content before and after to post value

Tags: jquery

i want to add below html code to `$('#formId').html()` before and after have to add `/html>` to post content through ajax call.

```html
<html>
<title>Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body ">
```

i am going to post formId values to generatescript but I want to add above html content to before formId to post data

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '/download',
  data: {
    filename: 'export.txt',
    content: $('#formId').html,
  },
  success: function() {
    window.top.location.href = "/generatescript";
  }
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ..??looks weird

Comment: @YoYo i am going to post one 'Id' data in html(). but i want to add some html data before that ID .. U can see the code that what data i wanted to add data is..

Answer (score 0):

use `.prepend` and `.append` your requirement. here is your tutorial it. http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
http://api.jquery.com/append/